# broadcastreceiver within android activity is not receiving intents after a while

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent

i am a beginner to android..i am facing the below issue....
Problem : broadcastreceiver within android activity is not receiving intents after receiving NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION  within a service started from that main activity..

More details:
i have an activity and an intentservice in my application.i invoke the service from the onCreate() method of the activity.
communication between the service and the activity is via a broadcastreceiver in the activity which receives the intent(say UIintent) i send from the service...this intent is basically to update the user interface based on the status available in my service....

my activity is able to receive the intent(UIintent) broadcast from the service until a certain point of time.after that my intent(UIintent) is not received in the activity.

I have registered for NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION within my service.
The point after which my activity is not receiving the intent(UIintent) is when the service receives the NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION intent.

Registering for the UIintent in my activity is done within the oncreate() itself.
I also tried unregistering in onPause() and registering it again in onResume() still in vain.Can someone help me in resolving this issue.
All the broadcast receivers are registered in code and not in xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try out intent filters if you are not using any, they shield the Broadcast Receiver from intent which you do not wish to process. Intent filters have to be applied on both the broadcast intent and the broadcast receiver.